How to approach Machine Learning with Circular distribution (Classification problem)
I have 41 continuous columns and all are distributed roundly to each pair:

I used:

SMOTE for resampling data ( my dataset is imbalanced)
Test dataset: last month in the data dataset. Train dataset: remaining data set
GridSearchCV for tunning parameters for RandomForest and LinearRegression and got ROCs like this:

Linear Regression

Random Forest

I believe this is a bad result. I think I missed an important step in feature extraction and feature selection to achieve good results and I believe that it related to the circular distribution.
How can I improve my models (I think we can focus on circular distribution of continuous columns)
